# Thevenin voltage (Voc) with a resistor in the way?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzPsPz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm still having trouble with how Thevenin voltages are obtained. Above is an example with designated terminals (red). What if there is a resistor in the way (R3)? Is Voc only R2/(R1+R2)? How can R3 not matter? How can a voltage be obtained, even if "open", without closing the circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of the Thevenin voltage is correct. R3 does not affect the result since no current is flowing in R3 and hence there is no voltage across it.  However, it will affect the Thevenin resistance so it will affect the voltage across a load connected to the red terminals. As for your second question, the Thevenin voltage is defined as the open circuit voltage at the load terminals so it will appear there in series with the Thevenin resistance.Voltages do not require closed circuits, currents do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I guess I am still confused as to the meaning of a resistor in Rth, that Vth will flow through in the equivalent circuit, but is somehow not the in the current that defines that voltage.

Comment: I am still confused over the last part of my question. Does a voltmeter not form a circuit with whatever it is reading?

Comment: @ccube In theory, an **ideal** voltmeter does not affect the curcuit, so, it does *"not form a circuit with whatever it is reading"*. In practise, the voltmeter s not ideal and could be considered as/replaced by a 10Meg resistor.